# Getting a NullPointerException when accessing a Fragment using findFragmentByTag()

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a main activity that extends FragmentActivity. When my app starts, this main activity places a fragment "HomeFragment" in the layout:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

   FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
   ft.replace(R.id.container, new HomeFragment(),"Home_Fragment").commit();

}
```

I also need to be able to access this fragment on a button click in a different Fragment, but I don't want to put "new HomeFragment" in the container. I want to access HomeFragment using findFragmentByTag() because I am constantly updating HomeFragment with dynamic widgets, so I don't want to open a new HomeFragment each time. Here is how I am trying to access HomeFragment on my button click in a separate Fragment:

```
public class MenuFragment extends Fragment {

ImageButton btnHOME;
private FragmentActivity myContext;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}


@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    myContext=(FragmentActivity) activity;
    super.onAttach(activity);
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fr_menu, container, false);

    btnHOME = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnHOME);

    btnHOME.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            HomeFragment hm = (HomeFragment)myContext.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Home_Fragment");
            Log.d("tag_name", "HomeFragment" + hm + myContext);
            FragmentTransaction ft = myContext.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            Log.d("tag_name", "FragmentTransaction" + ft);
            ft.replace(R.id.container, hm, "Home_Fragment").commit();

        }
    });

    return view;
}


}
```

**I am getting a NullPointerException and my app crashes when I click the button and "hm" comes out null.** There is something simple I am missing, but I can't seem to find what that is.

Here is my StackTrace:

```
05-12 13:50:05.643 9044-9044/it.anddev.bradipao.janus D/tag_name: HomeFragmentnullit.anddev.bradipao.janus.MainActivity@21ebabd8
05-12 13:50:05.643 9044-9044/it.anddev.bradipao.janus D/tag_name: FragmentTransactionBackStackEntry{22079980}
05-12 13:50:05.643 9044-9044/it.anddev.bradipao.janus D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
05-12 13:50:05.643 9044-9044/it.anddev.bradipao.janus W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x437c0160)
05-12 13:50:05.643 9044-9044/it.anddev.bradipao.janus E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: it.anddev.bradipao.janus, PID: 9044
                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:414)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.replace(BackStackRecord.java:449)
                                                                        at it.anddev.bradipao.janus.MenuFragment$1.onClick(MenuFragment.java:69)
                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4487)
                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18746)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604)
                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-12 13:50:09.423 9044-9069/it.anddev.bradipao.janus I/System.out: TRY_1
```

Comment: Try calling `.executePendingTransactions()` after calling `.commit`

Comment: I edited my code above, but I also tried adding myContext.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions, after calling .commit, but this did not fix my error.

Comment: Then it's sure, Its the result of mixing `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and `android.app.Fragment` as told by @sush.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna I edited my code above so that I am using getSupportFragmentManager both times, but the same error remains.

Comment: Is this the exact code you posted inside `onClick` ?

Comment: @ShreeKrishna yes, that's the code in onClick with the StackTrace for that same code

Answer (score 2):

You're adding the fragment with `supportFragmentManager` and finding it with `FragmentManager`. Please check that.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I have edited my code above, but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Post your null pointer exception. I doubt your onAttach  is not getting , so myContext is null

Comment: I posted my output and I am printing hm with myContext, and myContext is not null, but maybe it is still the issue?

Comment: How did u add menu fragment ? Check that.. Did u replaced home fragment check that

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. I am adding home fragment when my main activity opens and calls "setContentView(R.layout.main);" main.xml has a <fragment> layout that is menu fragment. What do you mean when you say did I "replace home fragment"?

Comment: Don't do replace fragment again , jst add n check

Comment: I did this: ft.add(R.id.container, hm, "Home_Fragment").commit(); but it is the same error, because HomeFragment is still null.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I altered my code to get it to work. I just added .addToBackStack when I first open my new HomeFragment:

```
   @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

   FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
   ft.replace(R.id.container, new HomeFragment(),"Home_Fragment")
   .addToBackStack("Home_Fragment").commit();
```